# Adding/Removing elements in Mongoose accordingly

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm new to Mongo/Mongoose and I am having trouble how to execute the following thing:

I am creating a simple app where it utilizes Yelp API to find nightclub / bars around the area where the user can search.

Users are presented a list of clubs and each list has a form to sent out to mongodb that can keep track of other users that reserved for that particular club.

I've made a Schema of `Clubs`

```
const clubSchema = new Schema({
  clubID: String,
  guests: [String]
})
```

where clubID is the club's ID and guests is simply an array of strings that will keep track of userNames.

I want to do the following thing:

1) When a particular `clubID` doesn't exist in the database, it will create a new one and insert the `userName` in the `guests`

2) If `clubID` exists and `userName` doesn't exist in `guests` (meaning that it's a different user) , it will push the `userName` into the `guests` array

3) if `clubID` exists and `userName` exists in `guests` as well, remove that `userName` from `guests`

I have the following pseudo code:

```
exports.UpdateGuestList = function(req, res, next){
  const clubID = req.params.clubID;
  const userName = req.params.userName
  const userEmail = req.params.userEmail;

  Club.findOne({ clubID: clubID}, function(err, existingClub){
    if (err) { return next(err) ;}
    // if clubID exist in the data base, check the following
    if (existingClub){
                     //1) if the current userName exist, remove it from guests array
      if (existingClub.guests.includes(userName)){
        console.log('Remove guest')
      } else{         //2) if the current userName doesnt exist, push it into guests aaray
        console.log('Push in gueest')
      }
      return res.send({"message": "done"})
    }

    // If clubID does not exist, create and save clubID
    const club = new Club({
      clubID: clubID,
      guests: [userName]
    })

    club.save(function(err){
      if (err) {return next(err)}
      res.send({"message": "done"})
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: what do you want ?

Comment: Essentially go on the logic of 1) 2) and 3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
if (existingClub.guests.includes(userName)){

  Club.findByIdAndUpdate(
        clubID,
        {$pull: {"guests": userName}},
        {safe: true, upsert: true, new : true},
        function(err, model) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    );
}
else
{
  console.log('Push in gueest')
  Club.findByIdAndUpdate(
        clubID,
        {$push: {"guests": userName}},
        {safe: true, upsert: true, new : true},
        function(err, model) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    ); 

}
```

Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, all of your code works as intended, it is just that you want to know how to update a specific club entry. To do this, just modify the javascript object and then `save()` it.

```
exports.UpdateGuestList = function(req, res, next){
  const clubID = req.params.clubID;
  const userName = req.params.userName;
  const userEmail = req.params.userEmail;

  Club.findOne({ clubID: clubID}, function(err, club){
    if (err) {return next(err);}
    // if clubID exist in the data base, check the following
    if (club){

      if (club.guests.includes(userName)){
        //1) if the current userName exist, remove it from guests array
        const userIndex = club.guests.findIndex(function (guest) {
          return guest === userName;
        });
        club.guests.splice(userIndex, 1);
      } else{
        //2) if the current userName doesnt exist, push it into guests array
        club.guests.push(userName);
      }

    } else {
      // If clubID does not exist, create and save clubID
      club = new Club({
        clubID: clubID,
        guests: [userName]
      });
    }

    club.save(function(err){
      if (err) {return next(err);}
      res.send({"message": "done"});
    });
  });
};
```

You should also consider adding this method as a static method to your schema declaration instead of including this method in a separate library. See http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html for more details. It might then look something like this in your clubSchema file:

```
const clubSchema = new Schema({
  clubID: String,
  guests: [String]
});

clubSchema.statics.UpdateGuestList = function (clubId, userName) {
  ...
};
```